# SMTP Exception 5.7.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, smtpclient

I am using ASP.NET Web forms and sending an automated email through our SMTP Emailing system. In my web.config I added this:

```
 <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="username@domain.com">
          <network host="111.111.1.1" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
```

Now I am writing this code to send an email:

```
               MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.From = new MailAddress("username@domain.com");
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress("username1@domain.com"));
                message.CC.Add(new MailAddress("username2@domain.com"));
                message.Subject = "Testing";
                message.Body = bodymessage;
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Send(message);
```

At the last line I am getting this error mesg:

> {"Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not
>   have permissions to send as this
>   sender"}

What is wrong here?

Comment: Talk to your mail server admin -- there apparently are restrictions on the From address or other limits that you will need to adjust your code for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there is authentication on the SMTP server?  Try using

```
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a message from your SMTP relay server.  Your code is working fine, but the message you're receiving back is saying that you don't have permissions to send on behalf of the e-mail address you provided in the "From".

Here's some stuff that might help:

- Your SMTP server may require authorization credentials
- Your SMTP server may not allow emails to go out from addresses outside of the current domain.  Check with your provider.
- You may need to add the e-mail address to an exception list

Answer (score -1):

SMTP is not configured properly on the server. Check the IIS of server or contact hosting support.